# Is there no duplicates param for pd.cut?

Tags: python, pandas, quantile

When I attempt to run pd.cut with a list of bins that includes duplicates (`[0. , 0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ]`), it returns the following:

```
ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([0. , 0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg
```

However, when I add `duplicates='drop'` (like is available for qcut), I get

```
TypeError: cut() got an unexpected keyword argument 'duplicates'
```

Is the original ValueError just misleading because duplicate isn't really implemented for cut, or am I doing something wrong? I'm on version 0.22. I can manually control for duplicates before calling pd.cut, but wanted to use existing pandas functionality if it exists.

Toy data/example to work with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[0, 1, 0.18, 0.2, 0.38, 0.58, 0.78, 0.98]})
bad_bins = [0., 0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
pd.cut(df['a'], bins=bad_bins)
pd.cut(df['a'], bins=bad_bins, duplicates='drop')
```

Comment: Looks like you're working on an older version, because this works fine for me. Upgrade to 0.23.

Comment: Concur with coldspeed this works for me with `0.23.0` what does `print(pd.__version__)` show? You've either upgraded the incorrect location or you need to restart the kernel

Comment: My bad - this container's on 0.22. Thnx.